# Exchange sorting List C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, if-statement

It jumps over   **if (newklädDataList[minst].märke.CompareTo(newklädDataList[j].märke) > 0)**, and i can't figure out why, can someone spot the problem?

```
public static void SortByMärke()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newklädDataList.Count; i++)
        {
            int minst = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < newklädDataList.Count; j++)
            {
                if (newklädDataList[minst].märke.CompareTo(newklädDataList[j].märke) > 0)
                {
                    minst = j;
                }
            }
            if (i < minst)
            {
                Swap(minst, i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: “jumps over” means what exactly? Skips the check? Or is the condition just never true?

Comment: What's the type of the collection and what's the type of märke?

Comment: Your exchange sort is probably wrong.

Comment: Ask a more specific question. This isn't a service for finding your bugs.  If a method like CompareTo is returning something unexpected then give us more to go on, like what you are comparing and why the comparison is not as you expect.

Comment: It didn't work because int minst = 1 and not i. I'm super embarressed. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how you have implemented your Märk class, but I can do without that and I'll just try to give a more optimal way of your in the implementation of Sort function. I think we should go beyond the .Net 1.0 and move on to another Framework, so take the last as fastly as you can.
Below is some code to add to your Märk class and then a wand implement the Sort method on the list and that's all done.

```
public class Märk : IEquatable<Märk>, IComparable<Märk>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ID: " + Id + "   Value: " + Value;
        }

        public int Sort(string value1, string value2)
        {
            return value1.CompareTo(value2);
        }

        public int CompareTo(Märk compareMärk)
        {
            if (compareMärk == null)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return Id.CompareTo(compareMärk.Id);
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id;
        }

        public bool Equals(Märk other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.Id.Equals(other.Id));
        }

        //...Add somme other codes
    }
```

Now look at how to use it

```
 List<Märk> newklädDataList = new List<Märk>();


            // Add newklädDataList to the list.
            newklädDataList.Add(new Märk() { Value = "regular seat", Id = 9 });
            newklädDataList.Add(new Märk() { Value = "crank arm", Id = 5 });
            newklädDataList.Add(new Märk() { Value = "shift lever", Id = 6 }); ;
            // Name intentionally left null.
            newklädDataList.Add(new Märk() { Id = 2 });
            newklädDataList.Add(new Märk() { Value = "banana seat", Id = 4 });
            newklädDataList.Add(new Märk() { Value = "cassette", Id = 3 });

            Console.WriteLine("\nBefore sort:");
            foreach (Märk märk in newklädDataList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(märk);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\r\r");
            newklädDataList.Sort();


            Console.WriteLine("\nAfter sort by Märk Id:");
            foreach (Märk märk in newklädDataList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(märk);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope it helps